# Microsoft OWIN branch (map) application with isolated properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin, webapi

I'm trying to make OWIN to host two isolated apps at the same time. They have a [special extension Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn433524%28v%3dvs.113%29) that allows doing it.

By looking at its code I see that it copies the current AppBuilder by calling [New() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt174077%28v%3dvs.113%29)

As per the New() method description: "The new instance share the same Properties, but will be created with a new, empty middleware list".

But what if I don't want it to share the same properties? This doesn't work for me when I, for example, try to configure separate Ninject in each. If I just follow [this guide](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application) I see it creating a property called "NinjectOwinBootstrapper" and if two apps try to do this, I get "An element with the same key already exists" error.

I kinda worked around it by copy-pasting the code of Map() extension, called it MapIsolated() and the only thing I changed in it is calling my custom IAppBuilder.NewIsolated() instead of just IAppBuilder.New() as it used to be.

```
public static IAppBuilder MapIsolated(this IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
{
    if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    if (configuration == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    if (pathMatch.HasValue && pathMatch.Value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        throw new ArgumentException("The path must not end with a '/'.", nameof(pathMatch));

    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    {
        PathMatch = pathMatch
    };

    IAppBuilder appBuilder1 = app.Use<MapMiddleware>((object)mapOptions);
    IAppBuilder appBuilder2 = app.NewIsolated(); // <----- this is the only line I changed here
    configuration(appBuilder2);
    mapOptions.Branch = (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>)appBuilder2.Build(typeof(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>));
    return appBuilder1;
}

public static IAppBuilder NewIsolated(this IAppBuilder app)
{
    var newApp = new AppBuilder();

    foreach (var property in app.Properties)
    {
        newApp.Properties[property.Key] = property.Value;
    }

    return newApp;
}
```

The original AppBuilder.New() creates the new AppBuilder and copies _properties and _conversions by reference:

```
new AppBuilder(this._conversions, this._properties);
```

And in NewIsolated() I copy properties by values, instead. Not even sure though if I need any of those default properties - there are 12 of them.

It seems to work alright, I wonder though if that's the right way of doing it. Maybe I just misunderstood the concept?